# My action is not called in the store. How to effectively debug Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I have a problem that I can't solve because I don't get an error message.

I use Redux Toolkit (Slice) to manage the state of my application. In particular, the recovery of my data via API requests.

I manage it in the following way:

- image.ts as a service, request to the API url

```js
/**
 * Get all images
 * @returns Promise<ApiResource<ImageDto[]>>
 */
export const getImages = (): Promise<ApiResource<Image[]>> =>
  FetchAPI.get<Image[]>(endpoints.images).then(apiResponseToResource)
```

- imageAction.ts to retrieve the data from the request

```js
/**
 * Get all images
 * @returns - All images
 */
export const getAllImages = createAsyncThunk(
  imagesActions.GET_ALL,
  async (): Promise<{ images: any[] }> =>
    getImages().then((imagesResource) => {
      return {
        images: imagesResource.payload,
      }
    }),
)
```

- imageSlice.ts as reducer

```js
export type ImagesState = EntityState<Image> & {
  meta: { requestStatus: string; error?: any } | null
}

const initialState: ImagesState = imagesAdapter.getInitialState({
  meta: { requestStatus: '', requestId: '' },
})

export const imagesSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'images',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder: ActionReducerMapBuilder<ImagesState>) => {
    builder.addCase(getAllImages.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.meta = action.meta
    })
    builder.addCase(getAllImages.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.meta = action.meta
      imagesAdapter.setAll(state, action.payload.images)
    })
    builder.addCase(getAllImages.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.meta = action.meta
    })
  },
})
```

- store.ts

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  ...
  images: imagesSlice.reducer,
  ...
})

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
})
```

My problem is that despite all this, I can't get my images back.

```js
const images = useSelector((state: any) => state.images)
  console.log('images', images)
```

```json
//console log output
images -> {ids: Array(0), entities: {…}, meta: {…}}
          entities: {}
          ids: []
          meta: {requestStatus: '', requestId: ''}
          [[Prototype]]: Object
```

After searching a bit, I noticed that the requestStatus and requestId of my reducer (slice -> createSlice) are not filled in.

I don't see where the problem comes from.

Comment: Are you using the redux dev tool in your browser?  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd

Comment: Yep, I can't live without it :D